# How to retrieve the title attribute through Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

This is my code : `print(browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("followers").get_attributes("title"))`. I am using `find_element_by_partial_link_text` because maybe the xpath could be unique for each user. But my code returns nothing. This is the element's adress:

```
<li class=" LH36I">
  <a class=" _81NM2" href="/username/followers/">
    <span class="g47SY lOXF2" title="3,862,378">3.8m</span> 
      " followers"
  </a>
</li>
```

So my question is how can i get the value in the title using `find_element_by_partial_link_text` ? Thanks in advance.

SOLVED : You can look at DebanjanB 's answer.

Comment: Looks like you want to extract the title of the span element, but you will find and catch the link element. Try to look into xpaths, first looking for the link containing "followers", then going one step down to the span, extracting its title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text of the *title* i.e. **3,862,378** isn't within any `<a>` tag. Hence you can't use `find_element_by_partial_link_text()`. Moreover the element is a dynamic element so so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following solution:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/username/followers/' and contains(., 'followers')]/span"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='/username/followers/']>span"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```

**Note**: As per the documentation the actual method is [`get_attribute(name)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) but not `get_attributes()`

Comment: Sorry :) I am new here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use following xpath to get the value.

```
print(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'followers')]/span").get_attribute("title"))
```

Comment: @DebanjanB : Just copy and paste OP code.Thanks for that.Nowadays so busy in work not able to contribute :-D

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can use `xpath` like this:

```
print(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class,'LH36I')]//a[contains(@class,'_81NM2')]//span[contains(@class,'g47SY lOXF2')]").get_attributes("title"))
```