# How to grab the price information from flight reservation site https://reservations.airarabia.com

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm very new to python and trying to learn webscraping. Following a tutorial, I'm trying to extract a price from a website but nothing is being printed. What is wrong with my code?

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://reservations.airarabia.com/service-app/ibe/reservation.html#/fare/en/AED/AE/SHJ/KHI/07-09-2019/N/1/0/0/Y//N/N")
price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fare-and-services-flight-select-fare-value ng-isolate-scope")
for post in price:
        print(post.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the first *title* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "isa-flight-select button:first-child span.fare-and-services-flight-select-fare-value.ng-isolate-scope"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//isa-flight-select//following::button[contains(@class, 'button')]//span[@class='fare-and-services-flight-select-fare-value ng-isolate-scope']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output of two back to back execution:

  ```
  475
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the title attribute through Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708661/how-to-retrieve-the-title-attribute-through-selenium-using-python/57708907#57708907)

---

### Outro

As per the documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't entirely understand the parameters of **EC.visibility_of_element_located**. Was _//isa-flight-select//following::button[contains(@class, 'button')]_ arbitrary?

Could you also help with this URL: https://www.ae.cheapflights.com/flight-search/KUL-LON/2020-05-30?sort=price_a       - I need to extract the price under class _"price option-text"_, but I'm not sure what I should choose for the visibility criteria or how.

Comment: @FL44ME i will explain it in a short while but for the other part can you  raise a new question as per your new requirement please?

Comment: I have posted another

Comment: @FL44ME Did you get a chance to look in to my answer in your _...have posted another..._ question?

Answer (score 1):

The first reason for that is because the webpage you are trying to **scrape** uses javascript to load the HTML so you will need to wait until that element is present to get it using selenium's `WebDriverWait`

The second reason is that the `find_elements_by_class_name` method only accepts one class so you would need to either use `find_elements_by_css_selector` or `find_elements_by_xpath`

this is how your code should look

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

chrome_path = r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://reservations.airarabia.com/service-app/ibe/reservation.html#/fare/en/AED/AE/SHJ/KHI/07-09-2019/N/1/0/0/Y//N/N")
price = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    lambda x: x.find_elements_by_css_selector(".currency-value.fare-value.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope"))

for post in price:
    print(post.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

Comment: Hey. I received the follower errors.

[12436:1444:0831/215122.158:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(943)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flight.py", line 20, in <module>
    lambda x: x.find_elements_by_css_selector("fare-and-services-flight-select-fare-value ng-isolate-scope"))
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: you can increase the wait if you wish. I put it as 10 sec but if your internet isn't the strongest you can increase it.