# How does expected_conditions as visibility_of_element_located works for an element while checking whether the page has loaded?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I would appreciate some help understanding the function of `visibility_of_element_located()` and to extract data under the class *"price option-text"* from the page https://www.ae.cheapflights.com/flight-search/KUL-LON/2020-05-30?sort=price_a

In follow up to [How to grab the price information from flight reservation site https://reservations.airarabia.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739736/how-to-grab-the-price-information-from-flight-reservation-site-https-reservati/57741604?noredirect=1#comment101924002_57741604)

Comment: What does the Selenium/python documentation state about `visibility_of_element_located()`? Did you read it? It seems like you are asking two questions here... you need to edit your question and pick one because only one question should be asked at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [get_attribute(name)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method or [text](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute would have sufficed to our need to extract the price information from the flight reservation site. However if you look into the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of the [website](https://reservations.airarabia.com/service-app/ibe/reservation.html#/fare/en/AED/AE/SHJ/KHI/07-09-2019/N/1/0/0/Y//N/N) the desired elements are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled elements which may/not be clickable/interactable as soon as [`(document.readyState").equals("complete")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709234/selenium-ie-webdriver-only-works-while-debugging/47710701#47710701) is achieved.

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Do we have any generic function to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-function-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleni/50329056#50329056)

As per best practices, in those cases you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) either for:

- [presence_of_element_located](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located)
- [visibility_of_element_located](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located)
- [element_to_be_clickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable)

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to sleep webdriver in python for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)

Hence in your usecase we need to use **visibility_of_element_located**