# Python Selenium Webdriver get text inside "data-original-title"

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a question about selenium webdriver.

Everything is working fine but there is one element I don't get to work.

That's the html tag when i inspect the element:

```
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/website/icons/rulesets/imgname.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="White Animals">
```

CSS Selector is always the same but the `"data-original-title"` is always different. I want to look for the text after data-original-title. "White Animals" in this example.

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "CSSSELECTOR"), "White Animals"))
except:
    print("Not available")
else:
    print("found")
```

Can somebody tell me what i am missing?

The img src is also changing so it's maybe easier to parse the img src?

I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the webpage on which you are trying?

Answer (score 3):

You can search by the `data-original-title` attribute

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-original-title="White Animals"]')))
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the *attribute* **data-original-title** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[src*='com/xxx/website/icons/rulesets/imgname'][data-toggle='tooltip'][data-placement='bottom']"))).get_attribute("data-original-title"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@src, 'com/xxx/website/icons/rulesets/imgname') and @data-toggle='tooltip'][@data-placement='bottom']"))).get_attribute("data-original-title"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the title attribute through Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708661/how-to-retrieve-the-title-attribute-through-selenium-using-python/57708907#57708907)