# Extracting texts from <li> items with selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I´m trying to get the text inside a /a tag in a nested ul-li structure. I locate all the "li", but can´t get the text inside a's.

I´m using Python 3.7 and Selenium webdriver with Firefox driver.

The corresponding HTML is:

```
[some HTML]

<ul class="dropdown-menu inner">
<!---->
    <li nya-bs-option="curso in ctrl.cursos group by curso.grupo" class="nya-bs-option first-in-group group-item">
        <span class="dropdown-header">Cursos em Destaque</span>
        <a tabindex="0">Important TEXT 1</a>
    </li>
    <!-- end nyaBsOption: curso in ctrl.cursos group by curso.grupo -->
    <li nya-bs-option="curso in ctrl.cursos group by curso.grupo" class="nya-bs-option group-item">
        <span class="dropdown-header">Cursos em Destaque</span>
        <a tabindex="0">Important TEXT 2</a>
    </li>
    <!-- end nyaBsOption: curso in ctrl.cursos group by curso.grupo -->
    <li nya-bs-option="curso in ctrl.cursos group by curso.grupo" class="nya-bs-option group-item">
        <span class="dropdown-header">Cursos em Destaque</span>
        <a tabindex="0">Important TEXT 3</a>
    </li>
    <!-- end nyaBsOption: curso in ctrl.cursos group by curso.grupo -->
    <li nya-bs-option="curso in ctrl.cursos group by curso.grupo" class="nya-bs-option group-item">
        <span class="dropdown-header">Cursos em Destaque</span>
        <a tabindex="0">Important TEXT4</a>
    </li>
                            [another 100 <li></li> similar blocks]                  .
                                                .
    <li class="no-search-result" placeholder="Curso">
        <span>Unimportant TEXT</span>
    </li>
</ul>

[more HTML]
```

I´ve tried the code below:

```py
cursos = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@nya-bs-option="curso in ctrl.cursos group by curso.grupo"]')
nome_curso = [curso.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text for curso in cursos]
```

I get the list with the correct number of items, but all of them = ''. Can anyone help me? Thks.

Comment: It seems the code should be ok, post the url if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were close. To extract the texts, e.g. *Important TEXT 1*, *Important TEXT 2*, *Important TEXT 3*, *Important TEXT4*, etc you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()` method:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.dropdown-menu.inner li.nya-bs-option a")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `text` attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='dropdown-menu inner']//li[contains(@class, 'nya-bs-option')]//a")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the title attribute through Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708661/how-to-retrieve-the-title-attribute-through-selenium-using-python/57708907#57708907)

---

### Outro

As per the documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Thks a lot, DebanjanB!! I used the get_attribute('innerHTML') and everything worked perfectly! Best, Gerson.