# Python + Selenium: I can't get print text from div

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Python + Selenium: I can't get print text from this div:

```
<div id="modal-content-18" class="modal-content" data-role="content">
    <div>
    SignUp Failed. Please Try Again.
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
resp = browser.find_element_by_class_name("modal-content").text
print resp
```

But it does not work.

Please help me.

Comment: have you tried a query by id ? `"modal-content-18"`

Comment: to go off @PRMoureu comment, there could be more than one element with that class name. perhaps query by ID, or wrap in for loop if there are many elements with that class name.

Comment: That element itself does not have any text.  The next div, nested inside of it, has the text.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Does it print the wrong thing? Does it crash? Does it throw an error? If it throws an error, what's the error?

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer xpaths because of cases like these. They can tackle many complex cases as well. Try the following:

```
resp = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="modal-content"]/div').text
print resp
```

In case the element isn't visible on the screen. The text method will be none. In that case you need the textContent attribute. Use the following then:

```
resp = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="modal-content"]/div').get_attribute("textContent")
print resp
```

Let me know if it works for you. Also make sure there is only one `modal-content` on the page. In case there are more than one, your css_selector is insufficient to identify this element. To check this you can run the following.

```
l = len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="modal-content"]/div'))
print l
```

if it returns a number greater than 1, then the `modal-content` class alone isn't enough and you will need to expand on your selection criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Induce **WebDriverWait** and **visibility_of_element_located()** and following locator strategy.

Using `CLASS_NAME`:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"modal-content"))).text)
```

Using `XPATH`:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='modal-content' and @data-role='content']"))).text)
```

You need to **import** followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**EDITED**
Check the `textContent` attribute value.

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"modal-content"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
```

**OR**

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='modal-content' and @data-role='content']"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
```

Comment: result: the print text is empty :'(

Comment: @SENTOTSAROYO : can you try that `print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"modal-content"))).get_attribute("textContent"))`

Answer (score 0):

The desired text **SignUp Failed. Please Try Again.** is within the child `<div>` so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal-content[id^='modal-content-'][data-role='content']>div"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal-content' and starts-with(@id, 'modal-content-')][@data-role='content']/div"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the title attribute through Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708661/how-to-retrieve-the-title-attribute-through-selenium-using-python/57708907#57708907)

---

### Outro

As per the documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)