# How to print element of div class value using python selenium web driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, findelement

How to print value for the class="valueValue-3kA0oJs5" from below snippet, Tried below things but no luck.

```
<div class="valuesAdditionalWrapper-3BfAIuML">
    <div class="valueItem-3JDGGSt_">
        <div class="valueValue-3kA0oJs5" style="color: rgb(128, 0, 128);">46.2625</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Using class name:**

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("valueValue-3kA0oJs5")
```

**using xpath:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="valueValue-3kA0oJs5"]')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="valueValue-3kA0oJs5"]')
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: How does the html code of the elements look like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python + Selenium: I can't get print text from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936583/python-selenium-i-cant-get-print-text-from-div)

Answer (score 0):

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="valueValue-3kA0oJs5"]').text)
```

Just use .text on the element found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text out of element then use `text` property on the find_element methods

```
value = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "valueValue")]').text
```

And if you want to grab the class attribute value of div element

```
classname = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "valueValue")]').get_attribute('class')
```